# "Invalid syntax" error with fstring for creating URL for api call

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, cs50

I'm in my final project for CS50 online through EdX, and I want to use an fstring just as was done in the last problem set for an API call, but I get this error:

```
File "populateDatabase.py", line 14
    url = f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(IMDBID)}?api_key={api_key}&append_to_response=release_dates"
                                                                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I thought just copying the code that was used in the problem set written by the staff of the class but changing the URL to make it relevant for my API would be fine. Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: What version of Python are you using? It might too old to support f-strings (although, normally the error points to the front of the line in that case iirc).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Python 3.9.5. I'm guessing since that's the latest version it would

Comment: Then check the lines above to make sure you aren't missing a quote or closing parenthesis.

Comment: Syntax Errors tracebacks don't always show where the syntax error is. Generally, it will be found in the line before. Show the code around the line you have provided or look for a syntax error before the line. This is not an f-string error from what I see.

Comment: @Jaet Please always give a snip code to get help. Just giving error does not help to understand what you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Jaet

Can you execute the following snippet?

```
import urllib
from urllib import parse

IMDBID = 'tt0068646'
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

url = f"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{urllib.parse.quote_plus(IMDBID)}?api_key={api_key}&append_to_response=release_dates"
print(url)
```

Works fine here (Python 3x).

Result:

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt0068646?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY&append_to_response=release_dates

> Be careful when copying code snippets from sites, sometimes the site
> text encoding (charset) is different than your IDE charset, and it
> mainly represents quotes with characters different, this generates
> errors. In this case retype quotes and special characteres.

Comment: You know what that works I'm so dumb I was doing "python [filename].py" and not "python3 [filename].py" Thanks for the help though!

Comment: hihihihihi
It happens in the best families.
I'm glad it went well.